# Camel recipientList so long it causes StackOverflow error

Tags: java, apache-camel, stack-overflow

I'm using Recipient List to initialize 30+ files with a header, before I write data to those files in the subsequent steps. (**edit**) I'm splitting a file in about 30 files by a given field, those new files need the same header as the original file. The headers and the split-by-type are requirements of the application that will consume the files.

Having more then 30, comma-separated, full file paths in one String results in a StackOverflow error when camel attempts to parse the String. I solved this (for now) by increasing the stack size.

But there must be a more robust solution, maybe I can use relative file paths somehow?

(**edit**) Code:

```
@Component
public class SplitterRoutesBuilder extends SpringRouteBuilder {

   @Autowired
   private ApplicationConfig configuration;

   @Autowired
   private MyFileFormat fileFormat;

   @Override
   public void configure() throws Exception {

     from(configuration.getFrom())
     .to("bean:splitFileByProductType?method=initialize(*)")
     // split file
     .split(body().tokenize(fileFormat.getLineEnd())).streaming().to("bean:splitFileByProductType?method=processLine(*)")
     .recipientList(header(SplitFileByProductType.WRITE_FILENAME_HEADER))
     .end();
    }
}
```

Then, in SplitFileByProductType:

```
   public void processLine(Exchange exchange) throws EmptyLineException {
       String line = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
       String originalFileName = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader(ORIGINAL_FILENAME_HEADER);
       // various checks and errorhandling omitted for clariry
       setoutputFileExchangeHeader(exchange, values[index].trim(), originalFileName, leftOversFileName);
       exchange.getIn().setBody(line + fileFormat.getLineEnd());
}
```

The actual work is done here:

```
private void setoutputFileExchangeHeader(Exchange exchange, String product, String originalFileName, String leftOversFileName) {
    if (isProductType(product)) {
        // a regular line, write to appropriate file
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(WRITE_FILENAME_HEADER,
                fileNameFormatter.getProductFileDestination(originalFileName, product));
    } else if (PRODUCT_COLUMN_NAME.equals(product)) {
        // this is the header line, write the header to all files
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(WRITE_FILENAME_HEADER, getAllFileNames(originalFileName, leftOversFileName));
    } else {
        // product not regognized, line goes to 'rest'
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(WRITE_FILENAME_HEADER, leftOversFileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe show a bit more of code what you are doing, and tell more of your use-case with the 30+ files, it seems a bit unusual.

Comment: doesn't sound like the ideal use case for recipientList... did you consider putting the file names in a list and using a splitter, for example?

Comment: @vikingsteve how would I start a route from a util.List during initialization, prior to the rest of the route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. I was able to reproduce it with following test using actual Apache Camel 2.21.1. `recipientList` fails on `StackOverflowError` with comma separated list of endpoints. However if you pass `List<String>` of endpoints, the route works as expected. So you can modify your `SplitFileByProductType` Processor to create List of endpoints, instead of comma separated String.

---

```
public class LongRecipientListCausesStackOverflow extends CamelTestSupport {

    private static final int COUNT = 300;
    private static final String BASE_DIR = "D://temp/cameltest/";

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:in")
                        .recipientList(header("to"))
                        .to("mock:done");
            }
        };
    }

    @Before
    public void clenup() throws Exception{
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(BASE_DIR));
    }

    @Test
    public void fails() throws Exception { //fails, throws StackOverflowError with header("to") of type String
        MockEndpoint mockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:done");
        String recipientListString = IntStream.range(0,COUNT).mapToObj(subDir -> "file:"+BASE_DIR+subDir).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:in","", "to", recipientListString);
        mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
        Assert.assertEquals(COUNT, new File(BASE_DIR).listFiles().length);
    }

    @Test
    public void passes() throws Exception { //pass with header("to") of type List<String>
        MockEndpoint mockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:done");
        List<String> recipientListList = IntStream.range(0,COUNT).mapToObj(subDir -> "file:"+BASE_DIR+subDir).collect(Collectors.toList());
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:in","", "to", recipientListList);
        mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
        Assert.assertEquals(COUNT, new File(BASE_DIR).listFiles().length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This does the trick. It never occured to me that setHeader takes an Object, not necessarily a String.

Comment: @Bedla, `to` API is not avaliable after `recipientList` in my case. I am using camel-http4 with spring boot. What could be the problem?